# Android Robolectric unit testing not working in a dynamic feature modules why?

Tags: android, robolectric

Robolectric unit testing fails with error message `java.lang.RuntimeException: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse {projectDir}/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/debugUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_`,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I started writing unit tests for my application using Robolectric in multi-dynamic feature application, I also just got a fair grip of dynamic feature modules and how best to share dependencies among them. Below is how I solved it.

[image: Dynamic feature architecture]

The problem is that a viewMoel factory dependency common to all which is inject by dagger resides in the library module and a viewModel unit test class resides in the DynamicFeat-1 always fails with error `java.lang.RuntimeException: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse {projectDir}/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/debugUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_`

And the unit test base class

```
abstract class BaseTest {

    lateinit var mockServer: MockWebServer

    @Inject
    lateinit var factory: ViewModelProviderFactory


    @Before
    open fun setUp(){

        setUpMockServer()
        configureDI()

    }

    @After
    open fun tearDown(){

        if(isMockServerEnabled()){

            mockServer.shutdown()
        }
    }



    abstract fun isMockServerEnabled(): Boolean

    private fun setUpMockServer(){

        if(isMockServerEnabled()){

            mockServer = MockWebServer()
            mockServer.start()
        }
    }

    open fun mockHttpResponse(fileName: String, responseCode: Int) = mockServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
            .setResponseCode(responseCode)
            .setBody(getJson(fileName)))

    private fun getJson(path : String) : String {
        val uri = this.javaClass.classLoader!!.getResource(path)
        val file = File(uri.path)
        return String(file.readBytes())
    }

    private fun configureDI(){

        //val coreComponent = DaggerCoreComponent.builder().contextModule(ContextModule(RuntimeEnvironment.application)).build()
        DaggerTestHomeComponent.builder().build().inject(this)
    }
}
```

The unit test class extends the base and sets up the viewModel by calling `super.setUp()` but this will always fail. Can anyone help me figure out how to make this work? I will be happy to provide more details if needed, am using robolectric `4.3`

Comment: They Won't... Robolectric has an open issue here: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/4975. I am also stuck at the same problem

Comment: were you able to figure out any solution for this?